# Spring controller doesn't work with mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run a simple Spring application but it's impossible.

I have this controller:

```java
@Controller("home")
public class Home {

    @RequestMapping("/showHome")
    public String showHome(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

This is `ViewResolver`:

```java
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
   InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
   viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

   return viewResolver;
}
```

When I run this program like that I'm getting `404 not found` and URL is: `http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/`

But, when I change my controller class and method like this:

```java
@Controller
public class Home {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String showHome(){
       return "index";
   }
}
```

My index page works.

Answer (score 0):

In your first version, `@Controller("home")` all it does is set `home` as the `Home` bean name, nothing else. The important thing is `@RequestMapping("/showHome")`. With this, you are saying that your `showHome()` method will be available at `http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/showHome`.

In your second version, you are using `@RequestMapping("/")` which sets no additional path and that is why `http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/` works.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks! But earlier when I make such a simple example and run the program it automatically starts the page and now I have to manually type the URL

Comment: What do you mean by "manually type the URL"? If my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accept it as the answer so that others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: Earlier when I made such a simple controller when I start the page it automatically started that controller, now  after `http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT` I have to add manually `/show/showHome`

Comment: With `@RequestMapping("/showHome")` that is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the path for ALL of the endpoints to begin with "home" you would need

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class Home {
 @RequestMapping("/showHome")
    public String showHome(){
        return "index";
    }
...
 @RequestMapping("/someOtherEndpoint")
    public String someOtherEndpoint(){
}

}
```

The above would be available at http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/home/showHome and  http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/home/someOtherEndpoint

Otherwise, as someone mentioned, you're just setting the name of the bean itself, and then using the "/" path that you declared on the showHome endpoint.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks! But earlier when I make such a simple example and run the program it automatically starts the page and now I have to manually type the URL

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood your goal.  If you want "http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/" to show "index", then what you have (`RequestMapping("/")`) is the correct way.