# Why Spring wont run right path automatic

Tags: java, spring

I have this controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class Home {

    @RequestMapping("/showHome")
    public String showHome(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

When I run program I got this URL: `http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/` and its 404 not found, but when I add `/home/showHome` its works. In such simple projects, earlier when I start the program, it automatically throws out the required address

Answer (score 1):

If you want `http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/` to be a valid URL returning the index page you need to change your controller as follows:

```java
@Controller
public class Home {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

With your current code (`@RequestMapping("/home")` and `@RequestMapping("/showHome")`), you are telling Spring that the index page will be available at `http://localhost:8080/E-CommerceFinal-1.0-SNAPSHOT/home/showHome` as you wrote.

Comment: Last time I made such a simple controller to run only one page the program automatically started that page. Even I added root path

Comment: With both `@RequestMapping("/home")` and `@RequestMapping("/showHome")` that is simply not possible. Maybe your IDE tricked you because the updated code was not the one running.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't cross post -- you've already gotten this answered (by the same people) here
[Spring controller doesn't work with mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661370/spring-controller-doesnt-work-with-mapping/69662201#69662201)